# UIBarButtonItems out of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a view controller with only a toolbar containing some bar button items, then I create an instance of this view controller and add this to another view but my problem is that when I test this on an iphone 6 or 6 plus the bar button items appear out of screen as you can see in the images.
I made the toolbar smaller and you can see that the buttons are out of the toolbar.
It's working fine on other devices, the problem is just with iphone 6 and 6 plus.
Does anyone know what's happening?

P.D. Im working with swift and xcode 6.4

[image: full width] 
[image]

**EDIT:**

this is how my view controller looks in interface builder
[image: IB]

and I'm adding the view with this code

```
toolbarDateSelector = ToolbarDateSelectorViewController(width: view.frame.width, date: date, onDateChanged: { (date) -> () in
            self.date = date
            self.getData()
        })

view.addSubview(toolbarDateSelector.view)
```

I can't add constraints to the toolbar because they appear disabled, maybe because the toolbar is the main view

Comment: Did you add autolayout constraints?

Comment: Do you use autolayout? If no, do you use autoresizing masks?

Comment: @mKane, I edited my question with more details

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is add constraints. Go to your view controller and select the constraints button (there are four icons in the bottom right of the screen. You want the one second from the right). A small box should appear above the icons, scroll to the bottom and select 'Add missing constraints' :)

[image]

Edit: You want the button named 'Issues'

[image]